# Why does dotnet cli only list one version of the .Net SDK but Visual Studio 2022 lists more?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dotnet-cli

When I list the SDKs installed for dotnet CLI, it only shows 7.x.x...

[image]

The current project I'm working on in Visual Studio 2022 targets .Net 6 and it builds fine.  When I click on the Target Framework dropdown it shows many more SDK versions.

[image]

Since I know my project is building fine targeting .NET 6, how come I only see 7.0.306 with the dotnet cli?

I Googled to see if Visual Studio install it's SDKs in a different location, but didn't find anything specific.

I did find that there's two different downloads of the .NET SDKs from [Microsofts's dotnet download site](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/).  There's the [Download .NET 6](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) and the [Download .NET SDKs for Visual Studio](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks).

But I couldn't find out if they install to different places in the filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio is showing you the list of *frameworks* available to target.

`dotnet --list-sdks` is showing you the list of *SDKs* you have installed.

That's not the same thing. You can use the .NET 7 SDK to target .NET 6, for example - that's fine. I suspect if you tried to target .NET 7 from VS when you only had the .NET 6 SDK installed, then either VS wouldn't list it, or it would fail to build - but that's slightly different.